# Retrieving image from binary data to imagefield

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mysql

I have stored my image in database as  format, how do i retrieve the image to  imagefield without using gridview or datalist? I just want to retrieve it to the imagefield only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the httphandler to retrieve the binary image, and then bind it to one image contorl with src property. Check this link.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1824646.aspx/1